# Read serial port vending machine from Android

Tags: android, serial-port, dex, android-usb

Currently I need to be able to read a serial port of a vending machine, I have read about USB host, and I have also found some libraries.

My question is: Is it really necessary to use an external library to be able to perform the serial port reading?
[Images of the converter](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-MP3uZWHvJnUkRUemFhZXNKaW8)

Comment: Is it a USB port or actual serial?  Because if its a real serial port, your first problem will be even connecting to it

Comment: The port I have to connect to is a Dex, but would perform a USB converter. [Images of the converter](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B-MP3uZWHvJnUkRUemFhZXNKaW8?usp=sharing)